# Class cast Exception - tabbedpane.getComponentAt(index)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to export the table data in the tabbedpanes into an excel file & I'm getting this exception

> javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

while trying to cast the output like this

> DefaultReportPanel panel = (DefaultReportPanel) this.tabbedPane.getComponentAt(i);

This is the class for the DefaultReportPanel

```
public class DefaultReportPanel extends JPanel {

JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTable table;   

public DefaultReportPanel(){
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    this.add(scrollPane);
}

public void setTable(String[] headers, Object[][] data){
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    this.table = new JTable(data, headers);
    this.table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    this.scrollPane.setViewportView(this.table);
}

public DefaultTableModel getTableModel(){
    return (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
}
```

This is the method where i was getting the exception

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, DefaultTableModel> getTableModels() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, DefaultTableModel> models = new LinkedHashMap<String, DefaultTableModel>();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++){         
        DefaultReportPanel panel = (DefaultReportPanel) this.tabbedPane.getComponentAt(i);
        System.out.println(this.tabbedPane.getTitleAt(i));
        if(panel != null)
        {
            models.put(this.tabbedPane.getTitleAt(i), panel.getTableModel());
        }           
    }       
    return models;
}
```

Any thoughts about what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assumption is incorrect as to where the exception is occurring.  I think it's happening here:

```
public DefaultTableModel getTableModel(){
    return (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
}
```

Why do I think that?  It's the only place (that you've shown) where you're casting to a `DefaultTableModel`.  When you created your table, you used this constructor from JTable:

```
public JTable(final Object[][] rowData, final Object[] columnNames) {...}
```

which does NOT create a `DefaultTableModel`.  It creates an on-the-fly implementation of `AbstractTableModel`.

**EDIT:**

To avoid the ClassCastException, some options are:

1. Ensure that your table has a DefaultTableModel by creating it
   yourself and then giving it to the JTable
2. Cast instead to an AbstractTableModel
3. Don't cast to anything and just use TableModel

Answers (2) and (3) require a change to the LinkedHashMap's type

Comment: how should this be changed now to run my program ?

Comment: Either (1) ensure that your table has a DefaultTableModel by creating it yourself and then giving it to the JTable, or (2) cast instead to an AbstractTableModel, or (3) don't cast to anything and just use TableModel.  Answers (2) and (3) require a change to the LinkedHashMap's type.

Comment: Awesome !! (1) works perfectly. Thank you. Could you put your comment in the answer, that would be helpful.